# Scale image to display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk

How can i scale image to the size of the screen?

what i've tried:

```
image:scale( display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to fit the image to your screen

```
local screen_adjustment = 1
local background = display.newImage("Objects/bg.png", true)
background.xScale = (screen_adjustment  * background.contentWidth)/background.contentWidth
background.yScale = background.xScale
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

just change the value of screen_adjustment to fit to your screen

Answer (score 0):

The screen ratio of Corona is fixed, check `build.lua`

You can do this by changing the width and height of the image(it will stretch the image)

```
bg.width = display.contentWidth
bg.height = display.contentHeight
bg.x = display.contentWidth / 2
bg.y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

You can also do this by using xScale and yScale of the image

**Note**: xScale and yScale must be the same if you want to remain your 1:1 ration of your image

By doing this, you can refer to DevfaR's answer